# Unable to install kernel source in kali Debian OS

Tags: header, apt

I have some issue my OS and I don't know how to handle, I have googled allot but no success, here is my problem.
I want to install Linux headers in my Kali Debian OS. I have used following commands,

```
$ apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

it's output,

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-3.18.0-kali3-amd64 : Depends: gcc-4.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

After I have entered following command,

```
$ apt-get install gcc-4.7

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-4.7 : Depends: gcc-4.7-base (= 4.7.2-5) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: cpp-4.7 (= 4.7.2-5) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libitm1 (>= 4.7.2-5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried some other commands as well, including following commands,

```
 sudo apt-get -f install
 sudo dpkg --configure -a
 sudo apt-get -f install
 sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade
 sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes dist-upgrade
```

As well as following aptitude command,

```
sudo aptitude install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

my system information,

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.18.0-kali3-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5) ) #1 SMP Debian 3.18.6-1~kali2 (2015-03-02)

$ uname -mrs
Linux 3.18.0-kali3-amd64 x86_64

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Kali
Description:    Kali GNU/Linux Kali Linux 2.0~alpha1
Release:    Kali Linux 2.0~alpha1
Codename:   n/a
```

Please guide me what's going wrong  Why I am stuck with this issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I share what I found and works for me.

My version:

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Kali
Description:    Kali GNU/Linux Kali Linux 1.1.0
Release:    1.1.0
Codename:   moto
```

My source list (/etc/apt/sources.list):

```
# Line commented out by installer because it failed to verify:
deb http://security.kali.org/ kali/updates main contrib non-free
# Line commented out by installer because it failed to verify:
deb-src http://security.kali.org/ kali/updates main contrib non-free

## Regular repositories
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
## Source repositories
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib
deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
```

and does the following:

```
# apt-get clean
# apt-get update
# apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-3.18.0-kali3-common linux-kbuild-3.18
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-3.18.0-kali3-amd64 linux-headers-3.18.0-kali3-common linux-kbuild-3.18
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 112 not upgraded.
Need to get 5,269 kB of archives.
After this operation, 34.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

I comment you that I had that problem because I realize mistakenly "distribution upgrade" to alpha version of Kali.

Hope this help.